# Need a table to fit full screen within div with another fix width div

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have the following HTML.

```
<body>

<div class="header"></div>

<div class="navdiv"></div>

<div class="mainarea">

<p></p>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Name</th>
    <th scope="row">Description</th>
    <th scope="row">Created</th>
    <th scope="row">Created By</th>
    <th scope="row">Modified</th>
    <th scope="row">Modified By</th>
  </tr>
</table>

</div>

</body>
```

I need some help with the CSS to structure the page correctly.

I want the header to be 100% across the top which I can do.

But I want the "navdiv" to be a fixed 250px on the left of the page.
Then with the "mainarea" div taking the rest of the page to the right of the navdiv.
I then also want the table to stretch across the rest of the page.

I have tried several variations and some work however I can't get the table to stretch across the rest of the space, it just either jumps below the nav, goes too far past the other content or only sizes to the content within it.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What do you mean by "I then also want the table to stretch across the rest of the page"? You want the table to span the whole width of "navdiv"?

Comment: How do your css looks like now?

Comment: What do you have so far? You wrote some of your tries worked. I guess you set float: left in the navdiv and the width: 250px; so then you could try using width:100% in the mainarea.

Comment: I want the table to span across the whole of the mainarea div, so that you see the nav on the left at its fixed size, then the table will fill the space on the right of the nav and will fit to the width of the browser. Hope that makes sense!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
.header { width: 100%; }
.navdiv { width: 250px; float: left; height: 400px; background-color: #F00; }
.mainarea { overflow: hidden; position: relative; border: solid 1px #000; }
.mainarea table { width: 100%; border: solid #F00 1px; }
/** hacks for IE6 **/
* html .mainarea { margin-left: 260px; }
* html .mainarea table { float: right; clear: none;  }
```

**Explanation:**

I'm essentially using the standard two-column `overflow: hidden` trick to force the main content to stay in its own column (as opposed to wrapping under the nav).  `position: relative` on the main content is to set it as the table's offset parent, so we can use `width: 100%` on the table to push it to the width of the main area.

The height on the nav, the background color, and borders are for demonstration purposes only.

**On the hacks:**

No other (modern) browser requires `margin-left: 260px`, as that is covered by the `overflow: hidden` (forcing it into two columns).

Still, at that point, the table seems to clear to the bottom of the nav (again, only in IE6). This is solved by removing any default clear (not sure that's necessary), and floating it to the right, so it doesn't take into account the size of the nav.

Comment: .. I like that you included the hacks for IE 6. Mind explaining the reasoning behind them?

Comment: Thanks Ryan thats worked!! Really appreciate it, was driving me mad.

Answer (score 0):

Have a go with something like this, (untested)

```
#header{
  width: 100%;
}
#navdiv{
  width: 250px;
  float: left;
}
#mainarea{
  width: 100%;
  float:left;
  margin-left: 260px;
}
table{
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  clear: left;
}
```

Comment: Hi david, thanks for the reply, I gave your sample a go, but the mainarea div goes below the navdiv, and the table goes to far to the right of the page and adds a scroll...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code. I wrapped your code with another div with class wrapper. You can modify the values. The navdiv class has 250px as you wish. You have to modify mainarea's 
width with percent. This is according to wrapper width. Just play a little and you will find what is the correct percent to fit with the wrapper's width.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>stackoverflow code</title>
<style>

.wrapper {
    width:900px;
    height:400px;
}

.header {
    width:900px;
    height:100px;
}

.navdiv {
    width:250px;
    float:left;
    height:100px;
}

.mainarea {
    width:72%;
    float:left;
    height:100px;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="header"></div>

<div class="navdiv"></div>

<div class="mainarea">

<p></p>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Name</th>
    <th scope="row">Description</th>
    <th scope="row">Created</th>
    <th scope="row">Created By</th>
    <th scope="row">Modified</th>
    <th scope="row">Modified By</th>
  </tr>
</table>

</div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: ?

```
.header{
  width:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
  }

.navdiv{
  width:250px;
  float:left;
  clear:none;
  margin:0 10px 0 0;
  }

.mainarea{
  float:left;
  clear:none;
  overflow:hidden;
  }

.mainarea table{
  width:100%;
  float:left;
  clear:none;
  }
```